# How do I get my scoll view to fill the entire free space in the vertical layout group in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, layout

I'm developing an application in Unity and I can't get the layout to behave the way I want it to.

[image]

The canvas is the red box and the contentWrapper is the green box. I want the green box to adapt to the canvas and leave a fixed size at the top and bottom for the header and footer. That works quite well so far. To make this work, I simply set stretch and stretch for the rect transform of the contentWrapper and specified the spacing at the top and bottom. Then I want the contentWrapper to be split between 2 objects, so I added a vertical layout group to the contentWrapper .

[image]

The first object is an picture whose width should be adjusted to the ContentWrapper and thus to the screen. The height should change in such a way that the aspect ratio is retained. I managed that too by activating controll child width in the ContnetWrapper and giving the picture an aspect ratio fitter with "Width Controls Height".

[image]

Now we come to my problem: I want a scroll view to completely fill the rest of the ContentWrapper. Depending on which settings I make, I get different results, but I don't get the desired result.

Comment: I think you could probably achieve that by using a `LayoutElement` with `Flexible Height = 1` ... could you share your exact setup?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! When using the layout element component, the problem arises that the picture is then treated as if its size were 0. If I also give the picture a layout element component, I have to either specify a height there or a ratio for the flexible height. The problem is that the actual height of the image is only determined by the screen resolution and so I can't provide a value. It seems that I would have to do that with a script in runtime. Or is there another solution?

Comment: Because the height of the picture is controlled by the width of the picture (because of the aspect ratio fitter). And the width of the picture is determined by "Stretch" to the parent, which in turn is determined by the screen width, which is unknown.

Comment: Always struggle with the same kind of advanced use cases ... sucks tbh ^^ Might have to go with a script indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by giving the picture and the scroll view each a layout element component. I set Flexible Height = 1 for the Scroll View and activated Min Height for the picture and then attached the following script to the Picture:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DynamicMinHeightSetter : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
        GetComponent<LayoutElement>().minHeight = GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.height;
    }
}
```

Thanks to derHugo for the Hint with the layout element component.